# Deriving a confidence interval for an unknown population mean

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem, confidence-interval

The times that a cashier spends processing each person’s transaction are independent and identically distributed random variables with a mean of µ and a variance of $σ^2$. Thus, if $X_i$ is the processing time for each transaction, E($X_i$) = µ and Var($X_i$) = $σ^2$. Let Y be the total processing time for 100 orders: Y = $X_1$ + $X_2$ + · · · + $X_{100}$

(a) What is the approximate probability distribution of Y, the total
processing time of 100 orders?

(b) Suppose for Z ∼ N(0, 1), a standard normal random variable:
P(a < Z < b) = 100(1 − α)%. Using your distribution from part (a), show that an approximate 100(1 − α)% confidence interval for the unknown population mean µ is: $($$\frac{Y − 10bσ}{100}$$)$< µ <$($$\frac{Y − 10aσ}{100}$$)$.

I have done part (a) and ended up with Y ∼ N(100µ,$σ^2$) using the central limit theorem, but I am unsure of where to start in part (b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal of the exercise to illustrate that you may derive a confidence interval that might not be the standard symmetric one (the usual conventional one that uses $\bar{x}$ as a pivot).

So starting with  *some*  $a$ and $b$ such that $P(a < Z < b) = (1-\alpha)$, we can write

\begin{align} (1-\alpha) 
& = P(a < Z < b) \\
& = P\left(a < \dfrac{Y-100 \mu}{10 \sigma} < b\right) \\
& = P(10a\sigma < Y-100 \mu< 10 b \sigma) \\
& = P(-Y+10a\sigma < -100 \mu< -Y+10 b \sigma) \\
& = P\left(\dfrac{Y-10a\sigma}{100} >  \mu > \dfrac{Y-10 b \sigma}{100}\right) \\
& = P\left(\dfrac{Y-10 b \sigma}{100} <  \mu < \dfrac{Y-10a\sigma}{100} \right)
\end{align}

As stated at the beginning, this is a general confidence interval not necessarily symmetric. IF one takes $a=\Phi^{-1}(\alpha/2)$ and $b=\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha/2)$, one gets the standard/conventional symmetric confidence interval. But the point is, if the only requirement is the interval having probability $(1-\alpha)$ without requiring symmetry, then there are infinitely many such intervals possible.

Moral: There is no such thing as "the" confidence interval unless one puts requirements (such as symmetry).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing after BruceET triggered a thought

Comment: You are welcome. I figured I will provide the details, just so I can throw in the clarification about the bigger picture view.

Answer (score 0):

If $X_1, X_1, \dots, X_{100}$ are a random sample from a distribution with
mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then $T = \sum_{1=1}^{100}$ has
$E(T) = 100\mu$ as you say, and (by independence) $V(T) = 100\sigma^2,$
not $\sigma^2.$ Hence, $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{100},$ where $\bar X = T/n = T/100.$

By the Central Limit Theorem, $Z = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{100}}$ should have nearly a standard normal distribution, as you say.
Thus, one has
$$ 0.95 \approx P(-1.96 < Z < 1.96) = 
P\left(-1.96 < \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{100}} < 1.96\right)
= P(\bar X - 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{100}, < \mu < \bar X + 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{100}),$$

where the last inequality is found my manipulating the event in the
penultimate term to isolate $\mu$ as in the last term.
The last term is the basis for saying that $\bar X \pm 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{100}$
is an approximate 95% confidence interval for $\mu.$
[I believe you may have mis-copied the last formula in part(b), and I hope
the specific case for $\alpha = 0.05$ helps you put it right and to
see how to derive the correct CI.]

Comment: Thanks heaps, the answer was pretty easy to get to after realising I had the wrong variance.